# No delay happening when sending messages between message channels

Tags: spring, spring-integration, dsl

I am new to Spring Integration DSL. Currently, i am trying to add a delay 
between message channels- "ordersChannel" and "bookItemsChannel". But , the flow continues as though there is no delay. 
Any help appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ordersFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("ordersChannel")
            .split(new AbstractMessageSplitter() {

                @Override
                protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> message) {

                    return ((Order)message.getPayload()).getOrderItems();
                }
            })
            .delay("normalMessage", new Consumer<DelayerEndpointSpec>() {

                public void accept(DelayerEndpointSpec spec) {
                    spec.id("delayChannel");
                    spec.defaultDelay(50000000);
                    System.out.println("Going to delay");
                }
            })
            .channel("bookItemsChannel")
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems for me that mixed the `init` phase when you see that `System.out.println("Going to delay");` and the real runtime, when the delay happens for each incoming message.

We have some delay test-case in the DSL project, but I've just wrote this one to prove that the `defaultDelay` works well:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ordersFlow() {
    return f -> f
            .split()
            .delay("normalMessage", (DelayerEndpointSpec e) -> e.defaultDelay(5000))
            .channel(c -> c.queue("bookItemsChannel"));
}

...

@Autowired
@Qualifier("ordersFlow.input")
private MessageChannel ordersFlowInput;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("bookItemsChannel")
private PollableChannel bookItemsChannel;

@Test
public void ordersDelayTests() {
    this.ordersFlowInput.send(new GenericMessage<>(new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"}));

    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();
    Message<?> receive = this.bookItemsChannel.receive(10000);
    assertNotNull(receive);

    receive = this.bookItemsChannel.receive(10000);
    assertNotNull(receive);

    receive = this.bookItemsChannel.receive(10000);
    assertNotNull(receive);
    stopWatch.stop();

    assertThat(stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis(), greaterThanOrEqualTo(5000L));
}
```

As you see it is very close to your config, but it doesn't prove that we have something wrong around `.delay()`.

So, it would be better to provide something similar to confirm an unexpected problem.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The delay is working as expected. My spring context was getting closed before the delay actually happened.